# How to set a print the contents of the div tag

Tags: javascript

I have a div tag on my web page which scrolls a long way to the right. I want to create a print button which the user can use to only print the contents in the div tag. 
Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        @media print {
            .noprint {
                display: none;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="noprint">
        Would not print
        </div>

        <div>
        This would print
        </div>

        <div class="noprint">
        Would not print
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a javascript based solution and you use jquery you can use this plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint

Then fire it on a click event.

```
$('#elementToClickOn').click(function() {
  $("#divToPrint").jqprint();
});
```